# Loaded model returning random results

Tags: keras

I am new to python and neural networks and have been trying to load and my models in order to decrease my training time. I am practicing with a stock so that I can get used to building my models. However, I am running into an issue when it comes to the results of my loaded model.

Here is my model:

```
checkpoint_path = "training_1/1.ckpt"
checkpoint_dir = os.path.dirname(checkpoint_path)

cp_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(checkpoint_path,save_weights_only=True,verbose=1)

input0 = Input(shape=(X_volume_train.shape[1], 1))
hidden111 = Dense(TOP)(input0)
flat0 = tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(Flatten())(hidden111)
hidden112 = LSTM(120, return_sequences=True,activation='relu', dropout=0.1)(flat0)
hidden113 = LSTM(100, return_sequences=True,activation='relu', dropout=0.1)(hidden112)
hidden114 = LSTM(80, return_sequences=True,activation='relu', dropout=0.1)(hidden113)
hidden115 = LSTM(60, activation='relu', dropout=0.1)(hidden114)
hidden116 = Dense(50)(hidden115)
hidden117 = Dense(40)(hidden116)
hidden118 = Dense(30)(hidden117)
hidden119 = Dense(20)(hidden118)
hidden120 = Dense(10)(hidden119)


input1 = Input(shape=(X_volume_train.shape[1], 1))
hidden211 = Dense(TOP)(input1)
flat1 = tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(Flatten())(hidden211)
hidden212 = LSTM(120, return_sequences=True,activation='relu', dropout=0.1)(flat1)
hidden213 = LSTM(100, return_sequences=True,activation='relu', dropout=0.1)(hidden212)
hidden214 = LSTM(80, return_sequences=True,activation='relu', dropout=0.1)(hidden213)
hidden215 = LSTM(60, activation='relu', dropout=0.1)(hidden214)
hidden216 = Dense(50)(hidden215)
hidden217 = Dense(40)(hidden216)
hidden218 = Dense(30)(hidden217)
hidden219 = Dense(20)(hidden218)
hidden220 = Dense(10)(hidden219)

input2 = Input(shape=(X_volume_train.shape[1], 1))
hidden311 = Dense(TOP)(input2)
flat2 = tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(Flatten())(hidden311)
hidden312 = LSTM(120, return_sequences=True,activation='relu', dropout=0.1)(flat2)
hidden313 = LSTM(100, return_sequences=True,activation='relu', dropout=0.1)(hidden312)
hidden314 = LSTM(80, return_sequences=True,activation='relu', dropout=0.1)(hidden313)
hidden315 = LSTM(60, activation='relu', dropout=0.1)(hidden314)
hidden316 = Dense(50)(hidden315)
hidden317 = Dense(40)(hidden316)
hidden318 = Dense(30)(hidden317)
hidden319 = Dense(20)(hidden318)
hidden320 = Dense(10)(hidden319)

input3 = Input(shape=(X_volume_train.shape[1], 1))
hidden411 = Dense(TOP)(input3)
flat3 = tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(Flatten())(hidden411)
hidden412 = LSTM(120, return_sequences=True,activation='relu', dropout=0.1)(flat3)
hidden413 = LSTM(100, return_sequences=True,activation='relu', dropout=0.1)(hidden412)
hidden414 = LSTM(80, return_sequences=True,activation='relu', dropout=0.1)(hidden413)
hidden415 = LSTM(60, activation='relu', dropout=0.1)(hidden414)
hidden416 = Dense(50)(hidden415)
hidden417 = Dense(40)(hidden416)
hidden418 = Dense(30)(hidden417)
hidden419 = Dense(20)(hidden418)
hidden420 = Dense(10)(hidden419)

input4 = Input(shape=(X_volume_train.shape[1], 1))
hidden511 = Dense(TOP)(input4)
flat4 = tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(Flatten())(hidden511)
hidden512 = LSTM(120, return_sequences=True,activation='relu', dropout=0.1)(flat4)
hidden513 = LSTM(100, return_sequences=True,activation='relu', dropout=0.1)(hidden512)
hidden514 = LSTM(80, return_sequences=True,activation='relu', dropout=0.1)(hidden513)
hidden515 = LSTM(60, activation='relu', dropout=0.1)(hidden514)
hidden516 = Dense(50)(hidden515)
hidden517 = Dense(40)(hidden516)
hidden518 = Dense(30)(hidden517)
hidden519 = Dense(20)(hidden518)
hidden520 = Dense(10)(hidden519)

input5 = Input(shape=(X_volume_train.shape[1], 1))
hidden611 = Dense(TOP)(input3)
flat5 = tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(Flatten())(hidden611)
hidden612 = LSTM(120, return_sequences=True,activation='relu', dropout=0.1)(flat5)
hidden613 = LSTM(100, return_sequences=True,activation='relu', dropout=0.1)(hidden612)
hidden614 = LSTM(80, return_sequences=True,activation='relu', dropout=0.1)(hidden613)
hidden615 = LSTM(60, activation='relu', dropout=0.1)(hidden614)
hidden616 = Dense(50)(hidden615)
hidden617 = Dense(40)(hidden616)
hidden618 = Dense(30)(hidden617)
hidden619 = Dense(20)(hidden618)
hidden620 = Dense(10)(hidden619)

input6 = Input(shape=(X_volume_train.shape[1], 1))
hidden711 = Dense(TOP)(input6)
flat6 = tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(Flatten())(hidden711)
hidden712 = LSTM(120, return_sequences=True,activation='relu', dropout=0.1)(flat6)
hidden713 = LSTM(100, return_sequences=True,activation='relu', dropout=0.1)(hidden712)
hidden714 = LSTM(80, return_sequences=True,activation='relu', dropout=0.1)(hidden713)
hidden715 = LSTM(60, activation='relu', dropout=0.1)(hidden714)
hidden716 = Dense(50)(hidden715)
hidden717 = Dense(40)(hidden716)
hidden718 = Dense(30)(hidden717)
hidden719 = Dense(20)(hidden718)
hidden720 = Dense(10)(hidden719)

concate_input = layers.Concatenate()([hidden120, hidden220,hidden320, hidden420,hidden520,hidden620,hidden720])

output1 = Dense(50)(concate_input)
output2 = Dense(1)(output1)

# multi-input , multi-output
model = keras.Model( inputs = [input0, input1, input2, input3, input4, input5, input6], 
                    outputs = [output2])


model.compile(loss=LOSS, metrics=["mean_absolute_error"], optimizer=OPTIMIZER)


model.fit([X_high_train,X_volume_train,X_open_train,X_low_train,X_close_train,X_adj_train,X_rsi_train],
                  [y_high_train],
                  epochs=EPOCHS,
                  callbacks = [cp_callback],
                  verbose=1)
```

After this I handle my preprocessing again and then use the keras.model.load function in order to make my predictions.

Here is the load section:

```
def MODEL():
input0 = Input(shape=(X_volume_train.shape[1], 1))
hidden111 = Dense(TOP)(input0)
flat0 = tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(Flatten())(hidden111)
hidden112 = LSTM(120, return_sequences=True,activation='relu', dropout=0.1)(flat0)
hidden113 = LSTM(100, return_sequences=True,activation='relu', dropout=0.1)(hidden112)
hidden114 = LSTM(80, return_sequences=True,activation='relu', dropout=0.1)(hidden113)
hidden115 = LSTM(60, activation='relu', dropout=0.1)(hidden114)
hidden116 = Dense(50)(hidden115)
hidden117 = Dense(40)(hidden116)
hidden118 = Dense(30)(hidden117)
hidden119 = Dense(20)(hidden118)
hidden120 = Dense(10)(hidden119)


input1 = Input(shape=(X_volume_train.shape[1], 1))
hidden211 = Dense(TOP)(input1)
flat1 = tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(Flatten())(hidden211)
hidden212 = LSTM(120, return_sequences=True,activation='relu', dropout=0.1)(flat1)
hidden213 = LSTM(100, return_sequences=True,activation='relu', dropout=0.1)(hidden212)
hidden214 = LSTM(80, return_sequences=True,activation='relu', dropout=0.1)(hidden213)
hidden215 = LSTM(60, activation='relu', dropout=0.1)(hidden214)
hidden216 = Dense(50)(hidden215)
hidden217 = Dense(40)(hidden216)
hidden218 = Dense(30)(hidden217)
hidden219 = Dense(20)(hidden218)
hidden220 = Dense(10)(hidden219)

input2 = Input(shape=(X_volume_train.shape[1], 1))
hidden311 = Dense(TOP)(input2)
flat2 = tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(Flatten())(hidden311)
hidden312 = LSTM(120, return_sequences=True,activation='relu', dropout=0.1)(flat2)
hidden313 = LSTM(100, return_sequences=True,activation='relu', dropout=0.1)(hidden312)
hidden314 = LSTM(80, return_sequences=True,activation='relu', dropout=0.1)(hidden313)
hidden315 = LSTM(60, activation='relu', dropout=0.1)(hidden314)
hidden316 = Dense(50)(hidden315)
hidden317 = Dense(40)(hidden316)
hidden318 = Dense(30)(hidden317)
hidden319 = Dense(20)(hidden318)
hidden320 = Dense(10)(hidden319)

input3 = Input(shape=(X_volume_train.shape[1], 1))
hidden411 = Dense(TOP)(input3)
flat3 = tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(Flatten())(hidden411)
hidden412 = LSTM(120, return_sequences=True,activation='relu', dropout=0.1)(flat3)
hidden413 = LSTM(100, return_sequences=True,activation='relu', dropout=0.1)(hidden412)
hidden414 = LSTM(80, return_sequences=True,activation='relu', dropout=0.1)(hidden413)
hidden415 = LSTM(60, activation='relu', dropout=0.1)(hidden414)
hidden416 = Dense(50)(hidden415)
hidden417 = Dense(40)(hidden416)
hidden418 = Dense(30)(hidden417)
hidden419 = Dense(20)(hidden418)
hidden420 = Dense(10)(hidden419)

input4 = Input(shape=(X_volume_train.shape[1], 1))
hidden511 = Dense(TOP)(input4)
flat4 = tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(Flatten())(hidden511)
hidden512 = LSTM(120, return_sequences=True,activation='relu', dropout=0.1)(flat4)
hidden513 = LSTM(100, return_sequences=True,activation='relu', dropout=0.1)(hidden512)
hidden514 = LSTM(80, return_sequences=True,activation='relu', dropout=0.1)(hidden513)
hidden515 = LSTM(60, activation='relu', dropout=0.1)(hidden514)
hidden516 = Dense(50)(hidden515)
hidden517 = Dense(40)(hidden516)
hidden518 = Dense(30)(hidden517)
hidden519 = Dense(20)(hidden518)
hidden520 = Dense(10)(hidden519)

input5 = Input(shape=(X_volume_train.shape[1], 1))
hidden611 = Dense(TOP)(input3)
flat5 = tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(Flatten())(hidden611)
hidden612 = LSTM(120, return_sequences=True,activation='relu', dropout=0.1)(flat5)
hidden613 = LSTM(100, return_sequences=True,activation='relu', dropout=0.1)(hidden612)
hidden614 = LSTM(80, return_sequences=True,activation='relu', dropout=0.1)(hidden613)
hidden615 = LSTM(60, activation='relu', dropout=0.1)(hidden614)
hidden616 = Dense(50)(hidden615)
hidden617 = Dense(40)(hidden616)
hidden618 = Dense(30)(hidden617)
hidden619 = Dense(20)(hidden618)
hidden620 = Dense(10)(hidden619)

input6 = Input(shape=(X_volume_train.shape[1], 1))
hidden711 = Dense(TOP)(input6)
flat6 = tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(Flatten())(hidden711)
hidden712 = LSTM(120, return_sequences=True,activation='relu', dropout=0.1)(flat6)
hidden713 = LSTM(100, return_sequences=True,activation='relu', dropout=0.1)(hidden712)
hidden714 = LSTM(80, return_sequences=True,activation='relu', dropout=0.1)(hidden713)
hidden715 = LSTM(60, activation='relu', dropout=0.1)(hidden714)
hidden716 = Dense(50)(hidden715)
hidden717 = Dense(40)(hidden716)
hidden718 = Dense(30)(hidden717)
hidden719 = Dense(20)(hidden718)
hidden720 = Dense(10)(hidden719)

concate_input = layers.Concatenate()([hidden120, hidden220,hidden320, hidden420,hidden520,hidden620,hidden720])

output1 = Dense(50)(concate_input)
output2 = Dense(1)(output1)

# multi-input , multi-output
model = keras.Model( inputs = [input0, input1, input2, input3, input4, input5, input6], 
                    outputs = [output2])


model.compile(loss=LOSS, metrics=["mean_absolute_error"], optimizer=OPTIMIZER)
return model

model = MODEL()
model.load_weights("/content/training_1/1.ckpt")
```

It works fine without saving out the weights and then loading, however, using this method I am significantly off (90%) in all of my predictions. Any help or guidance would be appreciated!
Thank you so much.